# Neo4j: Cypher count total paths found from allShortestPaths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to get the count on total number of paths found from allShortestPaths within queries of type

```
Match (n:Person{personid:123}), (m:Person{personid:456}), p =allShortestPaths(n-[r*1..6]-m) with reduce(weight = 0, rel in rels(p) | weight + rel.weight) AS weight, n, m,p return n, m, p,weight order by weight limit 25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way (by collecting the paths, getting the length of the collection, and then unwinding the collection back into path rows).

```
MATCH (n:Person { personid:123 }),(m:Person { personid:456 }), p =allShortestPaths(n-[r*1..6]-m)
WITH n, m, COLLECT(p) AS paths
WITH n, m, paths, LENGTH(paths) AS totalPaths
UNWIND paths AS p
RETURN n, m, totalPaths, p, reduce(weight = 0, rel IN rels(p)| weight + rel.weight) AS weight
ORDER BY weight
LIMIT 25
```